# curl_multi_add_handle produces an error in file "Unknown" on line 0

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use `curl_multi_*` to fetch multiple (around 50) URLs simultaneously since doing it consecutively takes a long time. However I get the following error message when executing `curl_multi_add_handle`.

> **Warning**:  (null)(): 10 is not a valid cURL handle resource in **Unknown** on line **0**

Here is the code:

```
//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

// Loop over pages and get set the URL to the cURL queue
foreach ($htmltogetlist as $source) {

    [...]

    // Get a cURL handle of the current URL
    $urls[$id]['ch'] = $this->_getCurlHandle($urls[$id]['url']);

    // Success
    if (gettype($urls[$id]['ch']) == 'resource' && get_resource_type($urls[$id]['ch']) == 'curl') {
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $urls[$id]['ch']); // << Produces error
    }
}
```

and `$this->_getCurlHandle` has:

```
// Set cURL handle
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

return $ch;
```

What's weird is that `$urls[$id]['ch']` is a valid `resource` of type `curl`, but yet I can't add it to `$mh` and the error is in the file `unknown` on `line 0`. Actually, I can even execute the handle and get a correct response from it, so I am positive it's valid. I just can't add it to `$mh`.

```
$content = curl_exec($urls[$id]['ch']);
$response = curl_getinfo($urls[$id]['ch']);
print_r($response); // Works
```

I know that cURL is working for multiple transfers. For example, the following code (which does essentially the same thing) works. I'm also sure that it's not the number of URLs that is causing the problem because I get the same error when limiting the database query to 1:

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");

curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1); // Works
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2); // Works
```

Comment: I would be highly interested in a solution to this. I have the same issue, the normal curl_init works just fine. But running 12 requests after each other is unaccaptable - so I am in the same positon like you. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Richard I got it working, but I really for the life of me don't know how or why it works now and not before. I started refactoring things, trying to minimize the error down to as little code as possible and suddenly it started working and the funny thing is that even when I thought I was reverting it back to how it was, it still kept on working. So I went from not being able to get rid of the error to not being able to reproduce it. Perhaps if you can break your code down something small you could submit a bug report to PHP.

Comment: I GOT IT : ) I have actually reported a bug to PHP. The friendly pierrick of PHP told me that its the same issue as #61141, apparently this is not a bug. The solution for this is to do a usleep, because the multi_select returns -1 and CURL expects you to wait for a bit AND THEN do an exec anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the issue #61141 mentioned by Richard in the comments above, and the solution given by pierrick indeed fixed the error for me.

This is the basic multi curl exec setup, as found in the PHP manual:

```
while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
```

However, the correct setup would be this one:

```
while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        usleep(100);
    }
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}
```

If `curl_multi_select` returns -1, halt the script for a little while and then run `curl_mutli_exec` anyway.

For further details: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61141

Comment: This is an old question and even after I submitted it I wasn't able to reproduce it after refactoring my code. I'll mark this answer as accepted because it *looks* like the right one, especially based on the comments in the bug referenced. However, if anyone can provide a different solution using reproducible code (for both the error and the solution), I'll mark that answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this on OSX with PHP 5.3.23, curl 7.30.0.

The fix was ensuring all the curl_init()'s were called before curl_multi_init();

Never saw this on other platforms (i.e. Linux)